# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "findByName" at path "_id" for model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting below error

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "findByName" at path
>   "_id" for model "Product"
>       at new CastError (/Users/me/projects/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
>       at ObjectId.cast (/Users/me/projects/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:156:13)

API written in Nodejs

DB: mongoDB

Controller:

```
exports.product_details_by_name = function (req, res) {
    Product.findByProductName(req.params.name, function (err, product) {
        if (err){console.log(err); return next(err);}
        res.send(product);
    })
};
```

router

```
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);
router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);
router.get('/:id', product_controller.product_details);
router.put('/:id/update', product_controller.product_update);
router.delete('/:id/delete', product_controller.product_delete);
router.get('/findByName', product_controller.product_details_by_name); // two get methods?
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
});

ProductSchema.findByProductName =  function(nam) { // is it right to do?
console.log("name"+nam);
  return this.find({ "name":  nam  });
};
// Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

**I am doing get call from postman:**

URL: **localhost:8080/products/findByName**

**Request Body:**

```
  {name: "name2"}
```

[image: js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the callback parameter in the findbyProductName function in your model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
  price: {type: Number, required: true},
});

// Export the model
let Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

exports.findByProductName =  function(nam, callback) { 
  console.log("name"+nam);
  Product.find({ "name":  nam  }).exec(callback);
};
```

Comment: Let me edit the question. I suspect problem with routing, but I am not sure and adding callback too.

Comment: I have the same problem with routing before it will enter the wrong route. can you arrange your routes like this


router.get('/test', product_controller.test);
router.get('/findByName', product_controller.product_details_by_name); 
router.get('/:id', product_controller.product_details);
router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);
router.put('/:id/update', product_controller.product_update);
router.delete('/:id/delete', product_controller.product_delete);

Comment: yes. This solved issue, but now I am getting below error: `Product.findByProductName is not a function`

Comment: try chainging the exports.findByProductName to module.exports.findByProductName in your model

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I am trying to add the method to model like here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html , but not sure if it is right to do or not..